# Go to a record in an Access 2016 form that opens in Datasheet

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

This program is designed to allow a food pantry to take attendance. To that end,

1. The admin enters attendance by selecting names from a table called *Dat_Household_Member* keying on a field called `IsHeadOfHouseHold` (true or false).
2. When the admin checks a box called *Attended* a record is written to a temp table which is cleared after the final report is written.
3. The admin doesn't complete entering attendance in one sitting. So, I need to take her back to where she last was.
4. I have a temp table into which the *Household_ID* is placed after each record is appended to the temp table. This way I know which record was edited last - easily.

I want to open the form - called *SigninSheet-Simplified* and go to that record while the form is in datasheet mode:

- `OpenForm` with a `where` clause doesn't do it. I get on one record. I want to open the form and go to that row. Should be simple.
- `FindRecord` won't accept a variable.
- `GoToRecord` doesn't either.
- `RunQuery` runs the query outside the form.
- `DoCmd.RunSql` returns an error even through the query from which the SQL comes works fine.

Here's the SQL -

```
SELECT dat_household_member.household_id, dat_household_member.[full-name] 
FROM dat_household 
INNER JOIN dat_household_member 
     ON dat_household.id = dat_household_member.household_id 
WHERE (((dat_household_member.household_id)=[forms]![MainMenu]![InProgress]) 
   AND ((dat_household_member.is_head_of_household)=True));
```

I'm open to any idea that will get this done as simply as possible.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC - Simply use [`SearchForRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.searchforrecord) with a *where* condition after opening datasheet form:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "SigninSheet-Simplified"

DoCmd.SearchForRecord acDataForm, "SigninSheet-Simplified", acFirst, _ 
                      "household_id = " & [Forms]![MainMenu]![InProgress]
```